# Specs2 Given when then A simple test failed

Tags: scala, specs2

I have a simple specs2 Given When Then test case from ([A simple Scala Given/When/Then style specification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078412/a-simple-scala-given-when-then-style-specification-failed)). The code cant compile. I dont know why is that.
The code:

```
class Specs2Spec extends Specification { def is =
  "addition" ^
    "given first number: ${1}"        ^ number1 ^
    "when add another number: ${2}"   ^ number2 ^
    "Then the result is: ${3}"        ^ result ^
    end
  lazy val number1: Given[Int] = (_: String).toInt
  lazy val number2: When[Int, (Int, Int)] = (n1: Int) => (s: String) => (n1, s.toInt)
  lazy val result: Then[(Int, Int)] = (n: (Int, Int)) => (s: String) => (n._1 + n._2) must_== s.toInt
}
```

The error:
**Error:(8, 39) overloaded method value ^ with alternatives:
  (a: org.specs2.main.Arguments)org.specs2.specification.Fragments  ........**

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the syntax has changed and you must mix in the GWT trait.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.structure.GivenWhenThenPage.html).